# Ruby variable name with double underscores

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions, double-underscore

Sometimes I see variable names with double underscore in the beginning and the end. For example:

```
Article.__elasticsearch__
```

Is there some naming convention related to double underscores in Ruby variable names?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> An initial underscore or double underscore basically indicates
>   "special/avoid overwrite" --meaning it's meant to reduce the
>   likelihood that someone else might define a method/attribute of the
>   same name. The most common occurrence is `__send__`.

From [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/150874)

Answer (score 4):

The author of the ElasticSearch gem made the wrong call IMO. At the end of the thread, Avdi Grimm, who is well-known in the Ruby community, [disagrees with the OP](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/150874#666023).

There's a reason you hadn't seen it yet and that it looks odd to you. It's because it's unidiomatic.