# What is @__instance__ in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables

Rails uses it [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b2eb1d1c55a59fee1e6c4cba7030d8ceb524267c/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb#L32) in `rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb`

```
      @__instance__ = Concurrent::Map.new
```

The meaning is mentioned nowhere in [Ruby variable name with double underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270937/ruby-variable-name-with-double-underscores).

Comment: It’s just an instance variable. Underscores usually indicate private / internal use.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer Stefan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underscore is a legal character in an identifier. It has no meaning whatsoever.

(There is one exception: local variables that start with an underscore will not generate a warning if they are unused.)

In other words: the meaning of `@__instance__` is exactly the same as the meaning of `@foobar`: there is no meaning.